# Monitoring traffic (calculating bytes transferred) on specific port without root access

Tags: linux, tcp, monitoring, traffic

Is there any way to monitor traffic on a specific port using linux commands. More precisely, I want to calculate number of bytes transferred on a specific port. I am aware that this can be achieved using tcpdump, iptables and many other ways. However, each of them require root access. Is there any way to achieve this without root access.

Thanks.

Comment: Did u try reading in /proc/sys/net?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Needed to solve this problem as well, whipped up the following script. Does not require root access, please modify as needed to also calculate transmit bytes (I only required receive bytes).

```
while true; 
do MARKER=$(ifconfig eth0 | grep "[RT]X bytes" | awk '{print $2}' | cut -c 7-); 
sleep 10; 
NEWMARKER=$(ifconfig eth0 | grep "[RT]X bytes" | awk '{print $2}' | cut -c 7-); 
expr ${NEWMARKER} - ${MARKER}; 
set $MARKER=$NEWMARKER; done
```

Also, change sleep interval to desired value for your purposes, redirect to a file if you need to keep the stats.